# bindParam error when trying to update a row in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I think I have been reading every single threat on stackoverflow regarding this problem, but I still cannot figure out why I am getting this error.

MySQL database consist of the following columnnames: id, stores, results.

I have a button inside a form. When I click the button "Select", the columnname records should update with +1. Everytime I click the button I get the error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/updaterecords.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/updaterecords.php on line 12`

Is there anybody who can see what is going wrong here?

**html**

```
<form action="updaterecords.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" value="333" name="id" />
  <button type="submit" name="selectStore" >Select</button>
  <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</form>
```

**updaterecords.php**

```
    <?php
    include 'dbconnection.php';

    if(isset($_POST['selectStore'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id']; // Line 8

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE stores SET records = records + 1 WHERE id = :id");

            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id); //line 12

        if ($stmt->execute()) { 
            $success = true;
        }

        $stmt->close();

        $mysqli->close();   
        if($success) {
            echo "Updated Succesfull";
        } else {
            echo "Failed: " .  $stmt->error;
          }
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: `bindParam` is used in PDO . In mysqli we use `bind_param`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I updated my code in the question here. I am using `bind_param` now, but are getting a 500 error - This page cannot be displayed.

Comment: @Saty why are you deleting relevant code in my question? I was asked where I get the id from. I post the code where I get the id, and you delete it.

Comment: Because updated question vanish below answer. If you have any further problem post a new question for that and by accepting answer close that question.

Comment: Ok my mistake then. As long as I am not getting yeld at because I am posting almost the same question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bindParam` is used in PDO . In `mysqli` we use [**bind_param**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

And

> mysqli does not support named placeholders.

Rewrite you code as

```
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE stores SET records = records + 1 WHERE id = ?");
 $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
 $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I just updated my question with the code I have now. When I click select now I get a 500 error page: This page is not working.

Comment: I am blind :-) Okay now something is happening. I get `updated succesful` now. The only problem is that it is always row 333 there is updated with +1. In my html I have `value="333"`. Should I set the `value="<?php $_POST['id']; ?>` like this in my html?

Comment: You need to add 333 dynamically!!

Comment: I thought I could do that like this: `value="<?php $_POST['id']; ?>` ?

Comment: How you identify row 333 in your database??

Comment: 333 is the id of that row. So as I see it the value is always inserted where the id in the database is 333.

Comment: But how you identify 333 is id in database??

Comment: Ah ok. So when I get the id and store from the database I use the code I just updated in my question. getdata.php